# No stash found when using git stash branch

Tags: git, git-stash

Using git, I am working on the master branch and have a few unadded and uncommitted files. I don't want to add them or commit them to the master. Instead, I am trying to stash the files and move to a new branch to add them and commit them there. However, this is failing with the error message: "No stash found.". Please see the log below:

```
$git status

# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Makefile
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   newfile.c
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And then when I try to use git stash

```
$git stash branch mywork
No stash found.
```

I am pretty sure the I used git stash in a similar manner before, but I can't see why it is failing now. How can I stash my changes to another branch and commit them there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `git stash branch` command creates a new branch from an already existing stash. Because you don't have an existing stash yet, you get the error message.

Just use `git stash` and *after that*, if you want to create a new branch from this stash, `git stash branch mywork`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.